# Swiper js the pagination is jumping by clicking on the bullets

Tags: javascript, html, swiper.js

[image]

When I click on the bullets the neighbor bullets work fine, but when I click the third bullet it jumps instantly to the proper slide but without a sliding transition. I need to have a proper transition effect during sliding.

```js
const swiper2 = new Swiper(".swiper2", {
    loop: true,
    direction: 'horizontal',
    setWrapperSize: true,
    // grabCursor: true,
    // effect: "coverflow",
    slideNextClass: "swiper2-next-slide",
    slidePrevClass: "swiper2-prev-slide",
    // initialSlide: 0,
    centeredSlides: false,
    /* coverflowEffect: {
        rotate: 0,
        depth: 0,
        modifier: 1,
        stretch: 0,
        slideShadows: false,
    }, */
    breakpoints: {
        0: {
            slidesPerView: 1.5,
        },
        480: {
            slidesPerView: 1.9,
        },
    },
    pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination2",
        clickable: true,
    },
    autoplay: {
        delay: 5000,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
    speed: 300,
});
```

```css
.opinion {
     padding: 70px 0;
     box-shadow: inset 0px -10px 0px 0px rgba(163, 163, 163, 0.2);
}
 @media (max-width: 480px) {
     .opinion {
         padding-top: 30px;
    }
}
 @media (max-width: 420px) {
     .opinion {
         overflow: hidden;
    }
}
 .opinion__body {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
     gap: 50px;
}
 @media (max-width: 1050px) {
     .opinion__body {
         flex-direction: column-reverse;
         align-items: center;
    }
}
 @media (max-width: 480px) {
     .opinion__body {
         gap: 20px;
    }
}
 .opinion__textbox {
     max-width: 816px;
}
 .opinion__textbox h2 {
     color: black;
     font-size: 4.8rem;
     font-style: normal;
     line-height: normal;
     font-weight: 500;
}
 .opinion__textbox h2 span {
     color: purple;
}
 @media (max-width: 480px) {
     .opinion__textbox h2 {
         font-size: 2.4rem;
    }
}
 .opinion__textbox > p {
     margin-top: 30px;
     color: black;
     font-size: 2rem;
     font-style: normal;
     margin-bottom: 30px;
     line-height: 30px;
}
 @media (max-width: 480px) {
     .opinion__textbox > p {
         font-size: 1.4rem;
         margin-top: 20px;
         margin-bottom: 20px;
         line-height: 20px;
    }
}
 .opinion__textbox a {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     gap: 25px;
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 1.6rem;
     font-style: normal;
     line-height: normal;
     padding: 16px 25px 15px 16px;
     border: 1px solid purple;
     background: purple;
     max-width: fit-content;
     font-weight: 400;
}
 @media (max-width: 480px) {
     .opinion__textbox a {
         font-size: 1.28rem;
         gap: 20px;
         padding: 12px 20px 12px 12px;
    }
}
 .opinion__swiper {
     width: 625px;
     height: 330px;
     position: relative;
}
 @media (max-width: 650px) {
     .opinion__swiper {
         width: 450px;
    }
}
 @media (max-width: 480px) {
     .opinion__swiper {
         width: 380px;
    }
}
 @media (max-width: 420px) {
     .opinion__swiper {
         width: 350px;
    }
}
 .opinion__swiper-item {
     width: 436px;
     height: 330px;
     background-color: black;
     padding: 20px 20px 43px 20px;
     transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
 @media (max-width: 480px) {
     .opinion__swiper-item {
         width: 343px;
    }
}
 .opinion__swiper-upper {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
}
 .opinion__swiper-rec {
     min-width: 50px;
     width: 50px;
     height: 50px;
     background: #fff;
     position: relative;
     margin-left: 12px;
     margin-top: 12px;
}
 .opinion__swiper-rec > div {
     position: absolute;
     width: 25px;
     height: 25px;
     background: orange;
     left: -12px;
     top: -12px;
}
 .opinion__swiper-site {
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 1.4rem;
     font-style: normal;
     line-height: normal;
}
 .opinion__swiper-textbox {
     margin-left: 12px;
     margin-top: 11px;
}
 .opinion__swiper-textbox h3 {
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 2.4rem;
     font-weight: 500;
     line-height: normal;
}
 @media (max-width: 650px) {
     .opinion__swiper-textbox h3 {
         font-size: 1.6rem;
    }
}
 .opinion__swiper-textbox p {
     margin-top: 30px;
     color: #fff;
     font-size: 1.6rem;
     font-style: normal;
     line-height: normal;
}
 @media (max-width: 650px) {
     .opinion__swiper-textbox p {
         margin-top: 41px;
         font-size: 1.4rem;
    }
}
 .opinion__swiper-textbox p a {
     color: orange;
     font-size: 1.6rem;
     font-style: normal;
     line-height: normal;
     text-decoration-line: underline;
}
 .swiper2 {
     width: 100% !important;
     height: 100% !important;
}
 .swiper-pagination2 {
     width: fit-content !important;
     bottom: -35px !important;
     left: 50% !important;
     transform: translateX(-50%) !important;
}
 .swiper-pagination2 .swiper-pagination-bullet {
     width: 30px !important;
     height: 5px !important;
     background-color: #d3d3d3 !important;
     opacity: 1 !important;
     border-radius: 0 !important;
     margin: 0 8px !important;
}
 .swiper-pagination2 .swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
     background-color: orange !important;
     box-shadow: 0px 2px 14px 0px rgba(64, 140, 255, 0.24) !important;
}
 @media (max-width: 620px) {
     .swiper-pagination2 .swiper-pagination-bullet {
         width: 10px !important;
         height: 3px !important;
         margin: 0 2px !important;
    }
}
 .swiper-slide.swiper-slide-active {
     z-index: 9999 !important;
}
/* .swiper-slide:last-child.swiper-slide-active .swiper-slide:first-child{
     right: 115px !important;
}
 */
 .swiper2 {
     width: 100% !important;
}
 .swiper2-next-slide {
     right: 115px !important;
}
 @media (max-width: 480px) {
     .swiper2-next-slide {
         right: 0px !important;
    }
}
 .swiper-slide:not(.swiper-slide-active) .opinion__swiper-item {
     background: #353535;
     transform: scale(0.9);
}
 @media (max-width: 480px) {
     .swiper-slide:not(.swiper-slide-active) .opinion__swiper-item {
         background: rgba(53, 53, 53, 0.5);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>EXP</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.min.css" />
    </head>

    <body class="main__body">
        <div class="opinion__swiper">
                <div class="swiper swiper2">
                    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="opinion__swiper-item">
                                <div class="opinion__swiper-upper">
                                    <div class="opinion__swiper-rec">
                                        <div></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <p class="opinion__swiper-site">
                                        exploit.org
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="opinion__swiper-textbox">
                                    <h3>Lorem 1<br />Ipsum lorem</h3>
                                    <p>
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                                        adipiscing elit. Nunc in mollis ligula,
                                        pellentesque facilisis lacus. Fusce
                                        scelerisque elit tempus, maximus ex et,
                                        convallis.hendrerit, scelerisque augue
                                        ut, bibendum eros. Vivamus semper odio
                                        vitae nibh pharetra, Donec dignissim in
                                        lacus non euismod...
                                        <a href="#">Read more</a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="opinion__swiper-item">
                                <div class="opinion__swiper-upper">
                                    <div class="opinion__swiper-rec">
                                        <div></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <p class="opinion__swiper-site">
                                        exploit.org
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="opinion__swiper-textbox">
                                    <h3>Lorem 2<br />Ipsum lorem</h3>
                                    <p>
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                                        adipiscing elit. Nunc in mollis ligula,
                                        pellentesque facilisis lacus. Fusce
                                        scelerisque elit tempus, maximus ex et,
                                        convallis.hendrerit, scelerisque augue
                                        ut, bibendum eros. Vivamus semper odio
                                        vitae nibh pharetra, Donec dignissim in
                                        lacus non euismod...
                                        <a href="#">Read more</a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="swiper-slide">
                            <div class="opinion__swiper-item">
                                <div class="opinion__swiper-upper">
                                    <div class="opinion__swiper-rec">
                                        <div></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <p class="opinion__swiper-site">
                                        exploit.org
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="opinion__swiper-textbox">
                                    <h3>Lorem 3<br />Ipsum lorem</h3>
                                    <p>
                                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                                        adipiscing elit. Nunc in mollis ligula,
                                        pellentesque facilisis lacus. Fusce
                                        scelerisque elit tempus, maximus ex et,
                                        convallis.hendrerit, scelerisque augue
                                        ut, bibendum eros. Vivamus semper odio
                                        vitae nibh pharetra, Donec dignissim in
                                        lacus non euismod...
                                        <a href="#">Read more</a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="swiper__manage">
                    <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination2"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@11/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Is there any chance to solve this problem? The problem only with pagination. There is not any problem with grabbing or sliding with finger in the mibile version.

Comment: Can you illustrating your problem on snippet above, because now I don't see pagination. Is different one then this on video...

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `breakpoints:` from  the javascript.
Just keep the following code-

```
const swiper2 = new Swiper(".swiper2", {
    loop: true,
    direction: 'horizontal',
    setWrapperSize: true,
    // grabCursor: true,
    // effect: "coverflow",
    slideNextClass: "swiper2-next-slide",
    slidePrevClass: "swiper2-prev-slide",
    // initialSlide: 0,
    centeredSlides: false,
    /* coverflowEffect: {
        rotate: 0,
        depth: 0,
        modifier: 1,
        stretch: 0,
        slideShadows: false,
    }, */
    pagination: {
        el: ".swiper-pagination2",
        clickable: true,
    },
    autoplay: {
        delay: 5000,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
    speed: 300,
});
```